# react native last textInput box not setting value at last onChange

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I have a group of 4

> TextInput

the first three set the value ok at 'onChange' method, but the last one is not getting set?

```
    onChange(index : number, value : string) {
    console.log(`onChange with index ${index} and val ${value}`);

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            console.log('capador 1');
            this.setState({firstVal : value});

            break;
        case 1:
        console.log('capador 2');
            this.setState({secondVal : value});
            break;
        case 2:
        console.log('capador 3');
            this.setState({thirdVal : value});
            break;
        case 3:
        console.log('capador 4');
            this.setState({fourthVal : value});
            break;

    }


    if (index === 3) {
        console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.firstVal}`);
        console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.secondVal}`);
        console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.thirdVal}`);
        console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.fourthVal}`); // why not setting?

    }

}
```

So I can see in the console log, that the value is correct, but on the index === 3, the value is not returned.

this is the log:

```
onChange with index 0 and val 1
capador 1
onChange with index 1 and val 2
capador 2
onChange with index 2 and val 3
capador 3
onChange with index 3 and val 4
capador 4
ya aya con input : 1
ya aya con input : 2
ya aya con input : 3
ya aya con input :
```

And this is how the TextInputs looks like:

```
                    <TextInput
                        ref="third"
                        style={this.state.pos > 1 ? styles.textInputStyle : styles.textInputNormalStyle}
                        keyboardType = "number-pad"
                        maxLength={1}
                        onKeyPress={(event) => {this.onChange(2, event.nativeEvent.key); }}
                    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` does not immediately set the value, you have to wait for state update. You can check the value in `setState` callback which is called when the state is updated. Consider the following snippet

```
this.setState({fourthVal : value}, () => {
    console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.firstVal}`);
    console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.secondVal}`);
    console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.thirdVal}`);
    console.log(`ya aya con input : ${this.state.fourthVal}`);
});
```

Hope this will help!